# How to label y-axis inversely

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to flip a figure vertically but label the y-axis inversely.
Please see this example:

```
Plot[2 Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 15}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

What I want is the following figure. How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can use the option [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) to achieve what you want:

```
Plot[
    2 Sin[x]+x,
    {x,0,15},
    Frame->True,
    ScalingFunctions->{Identity,"Reverse"}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to do it.

```
Plot[-(2 Sin[x] + x), {x, 0, 15}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Transpose@{Range[0, -15, -5], Range[0, 15, 5]}, 
    None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]